# IE CSS * hack and HTC files

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass, html-components

Quick question about using .htc files in CSS.

If I use * to stop anything but IE using the style and it's a file I'm using it on (htc, image etc), do other browsers load it in as well?

I've got a SASS mixin for box sizing but don't want to load the htc file if I don't have to.

```
// Box sizing
@mixin box-sizing($boxmodel) {
    -webkit-box-sizing: $boxmodel;
        -moz-box-sizing: $boxmodel;
        -ms-box-sizing: $boxmodel;
            box-sizing: $boxmodel;

    @if $boxmodel == border-box {
        *behavior: url(/js/boxsizing.htc);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other browsers don't identify `behavior` as a valid CSS attribute, so your .htc file will not be loaded by anything than IE.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the proprietary `behavior` property [gets parsed and interpreted by IE8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); you're warned against this in the [polyfill usage section](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill#usage):

> If you prefix the `behavior` property with a star, like seen above [sic], it
>   will only be seen by IE6 & IE7, not by IE8+ (it's a hack) which is
>   better for the performance on those newer browsers.

If you are not big on css hacks (or big on neat setups and performance), you should use [IE conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to include a separate stylesheet for IE7:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 7)|!(IE)]><!-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="majestic.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

You would also be able to use a custom mixin for the property and compile two versions of the stylesheet:

```
@mixin border-box($ie7) {
  @if $ie7 {
    //forget vendor prefixes, this is for IE7 only!
    behavior: url(/js/boxsizing.htc);
  } else {
    //remember the vendor prefixes this time!
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

Define `$ie7` as truthful in the `ie7.scss` and you're good to go.